# Directory missing after server restart

Tags: linux, centos

After restarting my server I have two directories that are not working. I can see them through `ls` but when I do `ls -l`, I get

```
?---------  ? ?     ?        ?            ? cgi-bin
?---------  ? ?     ?        ?            ? tmp
```

Trying to cd into either directory results in "no such file or directory". Is there a way I can get these two directories to work again?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld /path/to/the/directory`?

Comment: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unmount filesystem and run fsck on this drive.
or if it is root partition then force fsck on startup.
probably filesystem is corrupt

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is something sort of corruption with the directory. You probably need to run fsck on the file system that the directories reside on.

Worse case, you may have to delete those directories and recreate them.